# Do something 300px after leaves the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I have a code to display something when get 300px before the scroll reaches the bottom! When the bottom is reached, I want to get rid of this message when get 300px after leave the bottom!

It perfectly works when I reach 300px before the bottom, but it doesn't work when I try to scroll 300px back.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
  var docHeight = $(document).height();  // Document height
  var winHeight = $(window).height();    // Window height
  var minHeight = docHeight - winHeight; // Real document height
  var curHeight = $(window).scrollTop(); // Display the height according to scrolling

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //BEFORE
    if(curHeight + 300 > minHeight) {
      document.getElementById('copyrights').innerHTML = "Welcome to bottom";
    }

    //AFTER (doesn't work)
    if(curHeight - 300 == minHeight - 300) {
      document.getElementById('copyrights').innerHTML = "Good bye";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You didn't say what part of the code doesn't work.

Comment: Just edited, sorry! =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set a flag variable to hold the state of whether you already went to the bottom before or not, or else it will just say goodbye at page load. Also the second check should be if (curHeight <= minHeight - 300). So all in all something like the following:

```
var scrolledToBottom = false;
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
  var docHeight = $(document).height();  // Document height
  var winHeight = $(window).height();    // Window height
  var minHeight = docHeight - winHeight; // Real document height
  var curHeight = $(window).scrollTop(); // Display the height according to scrolling

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //BEFORE
    if(curHeight + 300 > minHeight) {
      document.getElementById('copyrights').innerHTML = "Welcome to bottom";
      scrolledToBottom = true;
    }

    if (scrolledToBottom) {
      //AFTER (doesn't work)
      if (curHeight <= minHeight - 300) {
        document.getElementById('copyrights').innerHTML = "Good bye";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Is `scrolledToBottom = true` a variable?

Comment: Yes. It's defined in the first line to false at page load and set to true when you get near the bottom for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `$(window).scrollTop()` is the current scroll height measured from the top of the window. To get the scroll position measured from the bottom of the window, you can use `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()`.

You might want something that looks like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var bottomOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if(bottomOfWindow < (document).height() - 300) {
        // you are close to the bottom
    }
});
```